# How do some services track email opens by each individual recipient?

Tags: http, email, http-headers, gmail, tracking

Some services such as [GMelius](https://support.gmelius.com/article/49-per-recipient-tracking) and [Close.io](https://help.close.io/customer/portal/articles/1073988-tracking-email-opens) and [MixMax](https://mixmax.com/pricing/) have started to somehow be able to tell *which* recipient has opened an email, out of an email sent to multiple recipients.

I thought email tracking was done via an invisible GIF or PNG. How would they be able to zero in on *which* recipient opened it though?

For that matter, is it possible to make sure the person who opened it isn't the same person who is viewing Sent Email?

Answer (score 0):

By using **unique filenames** or optional parameters.
This way the sender obtains the knowledge of:

- that the actual recipient have actually opened the mail;
- the (public) IP address of the recipient;
- and that the recipient uses a client which actually opens external resources (most probably without additional permission request) so it's a great opportunity to send malware to him or her, since it's expected to be loaded regardless of user intent.

On the sending side it means generating a unique email for every recipients, instead of sending one copy to many.